# override antd autocomplete dropdown hover color

Tags: css, antd

For antd autocomplete component, when hover dropdown, the option will turn light gray. Is there a way to override the color?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` to override the color?

Comment: I couldn't find the correct class to override

Comment: @jason135 Antd uses less variable for colors and in your case you can chnage this variable  `@item-hover-bg: #f5f5f5;` Refer the steps mentioned in docs https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an antd user but one quick lookup in the Ant Design components examples for AutoComplete exposes a bit of CSS you can override: `.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled)`

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Developer Tools > Elements > Styles with :hover applied]

Depending on your particular setup, you should be able to simply add that class plus pseudo (`:not`) in your custom CSS to override the color or any other styles that aren't included and fit the specs, and if that doesn't work you can always append  `!important` to the end of the value(s) (as mentioned first in the question comments by @PaulBaiju).

Comment: used `.ant-select-item-option:hover:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled)` to override hover

Comment: oops, yes should have caught that it was for hover not selected. Will update for anyone who comes across this

Comment: post edit, it appears even the hover pseudo isn't being used by antd for this as it applies an "active" namespace'd class on mouseover event. Your commented implementation does add an extra level of specificity that supersedes it but thought I'd make a comment on it either way. I had been meaning to try out Ant Design for some time but have been stuck in the Material (UI) world, so this was a nice, albeit very light, introduction. Thanks!